# Troubleshoot custom CLR audit trigger without source code?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, clr

I have a custom .NET CLR trigger that is hooked up to my database to handle slightly more advance insert, update, delete triggers. Basically it is tying in some data not readily available to the database such as workstation ID and user name. I do not have access to the source code as it was written many years ago by some other developer. We are rolling out a second instance of our software package and database. The new database is 2019 whereas the existing database is 2016.

I am running into an issue where on some tables the trigger is working exactly as expected and on some it is not capturing the inserts/updates/deletes into our audit table.

I have ensured that CLR is enabled on the database but that is the only troubleshooting step I was able to come up with.

Edit, not sure why I didn't try this before but when doing an insert from ssms I get this error:

Error

[image: 1]

Edit2: This is fixed. I was able to use dotPeek to look at the source code (we own it) and determine that it was trying to do a selct * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables and the new database had a bunch of tSQLt items that conflicted with the code. After disabling Unit Testing with EXEC tSQLt.Uninstall the CLR trigger works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MSSQL Standard. I've got some error code that I am going to add to the original post. That my help.

Comment: Without documentation or source code you're really going to be flying blind. Is it really not committed to Git or some other source code control? Perhaps there's deployment of configuration data required to make it work. Does the working database contain something named `Private_NullCellTable` in `sys.objects`? Does the failing database?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find the source code anywhere. I am still working on trying to dig that up but have not had any luck as of yet.

I am not seeing anything with the name Private_NullCellTable in either database.

Comment: The error text would be more useful than a picture of it, but if I squint really hard, I see something called `DetermineTableNameFromSchema`. I'm making a guess here based on that name, but it seems like there's something in the trigger's code that dynamically figures out a table name to do something with.

Comment: Since it's your own company's code you should be allowed to use .NET Reflector or dotPeek to decompile the assembly back to .NET source code, then you'll have something at least similar to the original source to work with. I have used both tools in the past to recover lost code for companies. But if you want to produce byte-for-byte identical compiled output again you could be "making friends" with Diff tools and ildasm to compare the MSIL output and rearrange the source code until it produces the same byte streams (ignoring compiler timestamps and serial numbers, of course).

Comment: does private_nullcelltable ring any bells? perhaps it's some worker table needed which doesn't exist in your new database?

Comment: Apologies for the image of the error, Had a hard time formatting the text correctly. You should be able to right click and open in a new tab, works better that way.